# Netlist of the transpiled circuit in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, transpile

I am new to running quantum circuits in Qiskit. In the IBM quantum learning lab, I transpiled a simple 4-qubit quantum circuit using a 7-qubit IBM quantum computer. I received a tranpiled circuit image as an output. Is there any script so I can get the transpiled circuit's netlist?- so I can rebuild the transpiled circuit from the netlist?

Comment: What is netlist?

Comment: provider = IBMQ.load_account():
transpiled_ckt = transpile(circuit, provider.get_backend('ibm_nairobi'), seed_transpiler = 13) ;
transpiled_ckt.draw(output = 'mpl'); # this line gives the equivalent circuit image

I provide a 'circuit' of 1 qubit with a Hadamard gate. When I transpile the circuit with the given script above, I get an equivalent circuit with the basic gates -square root of X gate and Z gate. But this new transpiled circuit is in the form of an image. Is there any possibility to re-create this new equivalent circuit directly from the script and make some changes?

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on what do you mean by a *netlist*.

If you are searching for a human-readable serialization format of a non-dynamic circuit, I would recommend you OpenQASM 2

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, qasm2

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.measure_all()

print(qasm2.dumps(circuit))
```

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q[2];
creg meas[2];
h q[0];
cx q[0],q[1];
barrier q[0],q[1];
measure q[0] -> meas[0];
measure q[1] -> meas[1];
```

To load it:

```
from qiskit import qasm2

circuit = qasm2.loads("""
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q[2];
creg meas[2];
h q[0];
cx q[0],q[1];
barrier q[0],q[1];
measure q[0] -> meas[0];
measure q[1] -> meas[1];
""", custom_instructions=qasm2.LEGACY_CUSTOM_INSTRUCTIONS)
```

That recreates the previously dump circuit.

Comment: Thank you @luciano for providing the script, it's been very helpful. According to your comment, qasm-2 library worked most of the time to rebuild the circuit, but it did not recognize sx gate in my case. I found this error: 'QASM2ParseError: "<input>:7,0: 'sx' is not defined in this scope"' .... if you have any comments for using any other library instead of qasm-2, would be appreciated. Thank you so much!!

Comment: oh.. you can add `custom_instructions=qasm2.LEGACY_CUSTOM_INSTRUCTIONS` to the `load`. I include it in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: consider accepting the answer